# Zend framework 2 get specific type services

Tags: zend-framework2, servicemanager

How can I get every class that implements or extends from a specific class ?
For example I want to get all of classes that instantiated from MyClassName class ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do what Exlord said , but if you want something framework specific , you can add your preferd classes in config file under a specific key and get all of them .
for example :

Module A :

```
return array(
    'MyClassName' => array(
        'Module\Service\ClassA' =>  'Course\Service\ClassA',
        'Module\Service\ClassB' =>  'Course\Service\ClassB',
  );
```

Module B :

```
return array(
    'MyClassName' => array(
        'Module\Service\ClassC' =>  'Course\Service\ClassC',
  );
```

and get all of MyClassName instances like this :

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
$MyClassNameInstances = $config['MyClassName'];
```

Comment: This is wrong, and it is not related with what the original author asked. This is just configuration and manual mappings. The correct response is by @Exlord